# document.getElementById("x").checked returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I made a script to show a video if a checkbox is checked.

HTML:

```
<p class="subParHeader" style="">Video or not</p>
<form action="#" method="post" style="font-family: Arial;">
<input type="checkbox" title="Click here if you want to input a video" value="" id="FormVidOrNot"><input id="FormVidOrNotInput" value="" style="width: 30%"></input></input>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById("FormVidOrNot").checked){

    document.write('<div class="div_video">');
    document.write(JSFormVidOrNotInput);
    document.write('</div>');

}
```

But every time I run the code it returns undefined, eventhough it runs perfectly here:

```
if(document.getElementById("FormVidOrNot").checked){
    var JSFormVidOrNotInput = document.getElementById("FormVidOrNotInput").value;
}
```

(this part is higher up in the code than the first script)

Comment: `input` inside `input` is not valid html. Also `id` need to be unique

Comment: user2181397 it is, I did it in another part of the code and it works perfectly and the id used is only used once in the HTML

Comment: As user2181397 said, unique ids.

Comment: inputs dont need an opening and closing tag just combine it like this: `<input id="FormVidOrNotInput" value="" style="width: 30%" />`

Comment: That snippet must be executing before the form is ready in DOM. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <p class="subParHeader" style="">Video or not</p>
  <form action="#" method="post" style="font-family: Arial;">
    <input type="checkbox" title="Click here if you want to input a video" value="Test" id="FormVidOrNot">
   <input id="FormVidOrNotInput" value="" style="width: 30">
  </form>
```

Note that we no need of input tag close

```
document.getElementById("FormVidOrNot").addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(document.getElementById("FormVidOrNot").checked){
      var JSFormVidOrNotInput = document.getElementById("FormVidOrNotInput").value;

      document.write('<div class="div_video">');
      document.write(JSFormVidOrNotInput);
      document.write('</div>');
  }

});
```